# USB keyboard DataOut callback function and RxReady Callback

Tags: usb, microcontroller, stm32

I am making a USB keyboard using stm32F0RBT6 micro-controller. I want to receive data from PC for Caps Lock and Scroll Lock leds. Do I need to initiate a callback funtion like those ones?

```c
static uint8_t  USBD_HID_EP0_RxReady (USBD_HandleTypeDef  *pdev);
static uint8_t  USBD_HID_DataOut (USBD_HandleTypeDef  *pdev, uint8_t epnum);
```

Any help regarding receiving data would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using ST standard library and also ST USB library?

Comment: yeah...m using standard library..but its not working..no clue indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A USB keyboard uses the USB class HID (Human Interface Device), the specification can be found [here](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/HID1_11.pdf). The state of the LEDs are set with a set_report message, which is transmitted over the setup endpoint (also called default endpoint in the document) which is also endpoint 0 (EP0).

The format of the report used for keyboards can be found in the specification (page 59).

Therefore you need to use the callback function `USBD_HID_EP0_RxReady` and parse the `set_report` message you received.

Comment: I tried this way...but I am not getting any DataOut or RxReady interrupt. In setup I also put a case : set report. I debugged it. But still nothing is changed. My micro controller is recognised as keyboard. The problem is with DataOut and RxReady. @Étienne

Comment: Parsing the set report sounds different. Can you please help me out with suggestion. Thank you. @Étienne